# Why do bicarbonates tend to be more soluble in water than carbonates, for Group 1 and Group 2 elements?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility

In Group 1 and Group 2, it is usually found that bicarbonates tend to be more soluble in water than carbonates. For example: $\ce{NaHCO3}$ has higher solubility than $\ce{Na2CO3}$

As most of the trends in s block elements are explained by lattice enthalpies, I think it has something to do with lattice enthalpy, but I’m not sure how we can say lattice enthalpy of $\ce{Na2CO3}$ is higher than $\ce{NaHCO3}$.

Comment: Grouo I left out. You will likely reverse the question but bicarbonate is less soluble than carbonate, molarity accounted too

Comment: @Alchimista Sorry but what do you mean by "Grouo I left out"?

Comment: @Gaurang Tandon.  Group 1 let out.  NaHCO3 is less soluble than sodium carbonate. That is also why the only answer provided until now is not correct.

Comment: To increase the chance to get an answer you could pose a completely right question. ..